# Remove object from array list with user input

Tags: java, object, arraylist

If i have 10 objects in an array list and i want to remove a specific one based on the userinput, how do i do it?

```
public ArrayList<SmallItem> Backpack = new ArrayList<SmallItem>();
Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = t.next();

public void dropItemByName() {
    if(Backpack.contains(t)) {
          Backpack.remove(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: is the user input the index for an object or the object itself?

Comment: Consider using a `Map` rather than a `List`.

Comment: what is the connection between the ArrayList and the userinput? you seem to have a list of SmallItem objects but your user input is a String

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check `Backpack.contains(t)` unless you're actually searching for `t` in `Backpack`. `t` is your `Scanner` object itself, not the input.

If you want the user to input the index of an object to be removed, then you'll want to make `userInput` an `int` and do this:

```
if (userInput < Backpack.size()) {
    Backpack.remove(userInput);
}
```

If you want the user to input the name or some other input referring to the object rather than its index, then you should write a method that takes `userInput` as a parameter and determines which `SmallItem` is to be removed from `Backpack` and removes it.

Here's an example of how that could be done if each `SmallItem` has a variable `name` of type `String`:

```
for (int i=0; i<Backpack.size(); i++) {
    if (Backpack.get(i).name.equals(userInput) {
        Backpack.remove(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

This example would remove the first `SmallItem` in `Backpack` that has a `name` that matches `userInput`. If you want it to remove every `SmallItem` in `Backpack` with that `name` value instead of just the first one, just remove the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it write I think you want to remove the item (t) from the list

So you have to change the variable (item) by the variable (t or user input) as shown below:

String userInput = t.nextline();

public void dropItemByName() {

```
if(Backpack.contains(userInput)) {
      Backpack.remove(userInput);
    }

}
```